# connect Access via c#

Tags: c#, .net, ms-access, ms-access-2007, connection-string

i need to open a connection to a remote access db.
   in the local environment to the remote acess db  is working great .
   when i run this application from production server (other server) it's fail with message

"
 It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view its data.
"

my code :

```
   conString =
       @"Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;"
     + @"data source=" \\150.248.248.38\d$\TestApp\vending.mdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=1234;";

      OleDbConnection connAccess = new OleDbConnection(conString);


    try
    {

        connAccess.Open();

        objDiningRoom.Connection = connAccess;

       ....
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {


    }
    finally
    {
        connAccess.Close();
        connAccess.Dispose();
    }
```

*Its not open in other place
thanks

Comment: Do you have access to this other server? If you type "\\150.248.248.38\d$\TestApp\" into START | RUN and click OK, does it open an Explorer window showing the destination folder? If so, can you right click and create a new text file? If not, you have a permissions problem. I'd definitely recommend against using an administrative share for access -- non-admin users are never going to have access to that, only administrators.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it is a permissions problem.
Make sure you give the IUSR  account (or whatever account ASP.NET runs as) read/write permissions to your database.

Answer (score 0):

you can try :[here](http://www.xlinesoft.com/asprunnerpro/docs/error_the_microsoft_jet_database_engine_cannot%20open%20the%20file%20(unknown).htm) 
copied from there :

> - This commonly occurs when your    database file is opened exclusively
>     by another application (usually MS
>     Access). Close all applications that
>     use this database and try again.
> - This error may occur if the account    being used by Internet Information
>     Server (IIS), (usually IUSR), does
>     not have the correct Windows NT
>     permissions for a file-based database 
>     or for the folder containing the
>     file.
> - Check the permissions on the file and    the folder. Make sure that you
>     have    the ability to create and/or
>     destroy    any temporary files.
>     Temporary files    are usually created
>     in the same    folder as the database,
>     but the file    may also be created in
>     other folders    such as /Winnt. If
>     you use a network    path to the
>     database (UNC or mapped    drive),
>     check the permissions on the    share,
>     the file, and the folder.
> - Check to make sure that the file and    the data source name (DSN) are
>     not    marked as Exclusive.
> - Simplify. Use a System DSN that uses    a local drive letter. Move the
>     database to the local drive if
>     necessary to test.
> - The "other user" might be Visual    InterDev. Close any Visual InterDev
>     projects that contain a data
>     connection to the database.
> - This error may also occur when    accessing a local Microsoft Access
>     database linked to a table where the
>     table is in an Access database on a
>     network server. In this situation,
>     please refer to the following article 
>     in the Microsoft Knowledge Base for a 
>     workaround: Q189408 PRB: ASP Fails to 
>     Access Network Files Under IIS 4.0